# I am trying to do the basic number guessing game on python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble writing the code of the basic number guessing game in Python. The objective of the game is to correctly guess a number from 1 to 10 picked at random by the program. I also put some help text that tells the users if they guessed too high or too low. I keep getting a syntax error. This is the code i wrote so far:

```
 print "Welcome to the number guessing game"
 print "I have my number..."
 import random
 while True:

    random.randint(1, 10)
    number = raw_input("What is your guess[1-10]: ")
    if number > random.radint(1, 10):
         print "sorry you guessed to high"
    elif number < random.radint(1, 10):
         print "You guessed to low"
    elif number == random.radint(1, 10):
         print "You guessed right thanks for playing"
         break
    else: raw_input("What is your guess[1-10]: ")
```

Comment: It's extremely unhelpful to say that you get an error, then not say what the error is.

Comment: and again, what's the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `randint` not `radint`. You are creating a new random number for every test; you should assign a variable to a random number outside of the while loop.

```
r = random.randint(1, 10)
```

You must indent `if:` `else:` blocks - Python is layout sensitive, e.g.

```
if number > r:
    print "sorry you guessed to high"
```

You are comparing against a `str`, need to convert the input to an `int()`.

```
number = int(raw_input("What is your guess[1-10]: "))
```

You have an unnecessary `else:` condition at the end.
So putting it all together:

```
import random
print "Welcome to the number guessing game"
print "I have my number..."
r = random.randint(1, 10)
while True:
    number = int(raw_input("What is your guess[1-10]: "))
    if number > r:
        print "sorry you guessed to high"
    elif number < r:
        print "You guessed to low"
    else:
        print "You guessed right thanks for playing"
        break
```

You could change the `while` loop to cover the condition:

```
import random
print "Welcome to the number guessing game"
print "I have my number..."
number = 0
r = random.randint(1, 10)
while number != r:
    number = int(raw_input("What is your guess[1-10]: "))
    if number > r:
        print "sorry you guessed to high"
    elif number < r:
        print "You guessed to low"
print "You guessed right thanks for playing"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AChampion i appreciate your intellect, and im trying to get use to writing code on here it is a little confusing.